# Prevent overlapping edges on AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, amazon-neptune, graph-notebook

I have a Tinkerpop graph database on AWS Neptune.

In some cases, I have more than one edge connecting two nodes.

In the screenshot below, there is a node for 'Gary Barlow' and there is a node for 'All That I've Given Away'. Two edges connect these nodes, but those edges have labels which are overlapping. This makes the edge labels unreadable.

Is there a way to stop these edges and edge labels from overlapping?

Perhaps using [Neptune magics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/notebooks-magics.html#notebooks-cell-magics-graph-notebook-vis-options)?

[image: Close up of graph]

Comment: I have a writeup on this. I'll find it and paste it here. You just have to tweak the layout configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [description of how to do this](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/issues/157) in that Git Issue for the graph-notebook project.

In summary, you just have to change the layout option used by the underlying renderer. By default all graph diagrams are drawn using the `straightCross` layout. However in cases where there are parallel edges in the same direction between two nodes, the edges tend to be drawn on top of each other. In such cases, the `dynamic` layout produces more pleasing visuals. We should update the sample notebooks to demonstrate how to make these changes.

The `%%graph_notebook_vis_options` command with the following JSON is all that is needed. You can of course keep any other changes you may have already made.

```json
%%graph_notebook_vis_options
{
  "nodes": {
    "borderWidthSelected": 0,
    "borderWidth": 0,
    "color": {
      "background": "rgba(210, 229, 255, 1)",
      "border": "transparent",
      "highlight": {
        "background": "rgba(9, 104, 178, 1)",
        "border": "rgba(8, 62, 100, 1)"
      }
    },
    "shadow": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "shape": "circle",
    "widthConstraint": {
      "minimum": 70,
      "maximum": 70
    },
    "font": {
      "face": "courier new",
      "color": "black",
      "size": 12
    }
  },
  "edges": {
    "color": {
      "inherit": false
    },
    "smooth": {
      "enabled": true,
      "type": "dynamic"
    },
    "arrows": {
      "to": {
        "enabled": true,
        "type": "arrow"
      }
    },
    "font": {
      "face": "courier new"
    }
  },
  "interaction": {
    "hover": true,
    "hoverConnectedEdges": true,
    "selectConnectedEdges": false
  },
  "physics": {
    "minVelocity": 0.75,
    "barnesHut": {
      "centralGravity": 0.1,
      "gravitationalConstant": -50450,
      "springLength": 95,
      "springConstant": 0.04,
      "damping": 0.09,
      "avoidOverlap": 0.1
    },
    "solver": "barnesHut",
    "enabled": true,
    "adaptiveTimestep": true,
    "stabilization": {
      "enabled": true,
      "iterations": 1
    }
  }
}
```